# Powershell to add columns, remove lines and fill text in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

Total Powershell noob here. Please help!

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Office,First Name,Last Name,email
Pancacke Group,Lidia,Gheno,lidiapancackes@yahoo.com
Miller Tracy Carmel Valley,Paulina,Mastros,paulina@gmail.com
```

I need to have a powershell way to make it look like this:

```
,,,Pancacke Group,Test,Lidia,Gheno,lidiapancackes@yahoo.com
,,,Miller Tracy Carmel Valley,Test,Paulina,Mastros,paulina@gmail.com
```

Summarizing needs:

1. Add three columns before the first column, Office
2. Add another column between Office and First Name
3. Fill the column between Office and First Name with the word `Test`
4. Remove first line with the Header

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `(gc in.csv) -replace '^(.*?),', ',,,$1,Test,' | select -skip 1 | sc out.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1

```
import-csv "C:\temp\test\test.csv" | 
    select col1, col2, col3, Office, @{N="Col4";E={"Test"}}, 'First Name', 'Last Name', email | 
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
            select -skip 1 | 
                out-file "C:\temp\test\result.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Select-Object "col1", "col2", "col3" , Office, "col4", "First Name", "Last Name", email | Export-Csv file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Above one liner prepends three columns at the begin, and one between office and first name. Next step remove the first line:

```
Get-Content file.csv | select -Skip 1 | out-file file.csv
```

Both steps as one-line:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Select-Object "col1", "col2", "col3" , Office, "col4", "First Name", "Last Name", email | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | out-file file.csv
```

Hope thats what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
get-content "C:\temp\test\test.csv" |
    %{$Cols=$_ -split "," ;  ",,,{0},Test,{1},{2},{3}" -f $Cols[0],$Cols[1],$Cols[2],$Cols[3]} | 
        out-file "C:\temp\test\result.txt"
```